Thin lens focal length vs perspective
Thin lens and perspective
It's well regarded focal length of a camera lens does not affect perspective.
While by using the thin lens equation
$$\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{f}$$
we can compute the magnification to be
$$m=\frac{i}{s}=\frac{f}{f-s}$$
Thus with two tall objects of same height and different distances from center, their relative image size difference would work out to be
$$\frac{f-s_1}{f-s_2}$$
which depends on the focal length, unlike the pinhole case.
My understanding of perspective is the extent to which farther objects appear smaller.
So I'm confused. One way to explain it is f is usually very small compared to s, so it may be dropped. Also the lens movement while focusing. But it's not convincing because people say f won't affect perspective 'at all'. Considering thick lenses and lens system, maybe our understanding of focal length is different? Will this get worse for macro?

focal length of a lens (thin or real) absolutely does affect perspective...

@twalberg Only indirectly, in that it affects how far the camera will be placed from the subject to get desired framing of the subject. The only thing that actually affects perspective is camera position. Period.

The thins lens equation breaks down at macro distances for two main reasons: 1) as the lens is focused at shorter and shorter distances, the actual focal length changes and 2) the difference between S1 and S2 becomes proportionally larger by several orders of magnitude compared to more conventional focus/subject distances, where it is practically nil.

@MichaelC every claim about focal length not affecting perspective only gives qualitative answers with or without examples, which is less convincing than math. If the statement is true I would genuinely like a proof when and why my equation, that says perspective depends on f, breaks down.

cosaty https://www.australianlight.com.au/blog/post/myth_busting_focal_length_and_perspective/

@cosaty The complicated answer is because there's no such thing as a theoretical thin lens with zero thickness. The thin lens equation ignores the difference between the location of the rear nodal point and the front nodal point of a single lens with actual thickness. It's further complicated by compound lenses, where the nodal points may not even be equidistant from the entrance pupil. These must be taken into account with more involved equations.

@cosaty Is what you're talking about actually perspective, and not geometric distortion from differing lens projections (rectilinear, fisheye, etc.)? If the rear nodal point is in the same position, the perspective will be the same, even if the projection is not. That is, the same part of the scene will be covered by items in the foreground, and the same parts of the background will be visible to the camera. Perspective is not about how the subject's shape is projected onto a 2D sensor, it's about what is visible and not visible.

@MichaelC if in the simplest case the projection depends on f, then I could guess in more complicated cases it would depend on f even more, that could be justified in the wikipedia's formulas. But I do agree how they interact gets complicated - even the definition of eff/front/back focal length is not that simple. I also think our interpretations of perspective are all interchangeable.

@cosaty "I also think our interpretations of perspective are all interchangeable." And that's where I think you're in error. Perspective is totally dependent on the position of the entrance pupil and absolutely nothing else. Period. No matter the focal length, and no matter the projection, if the entrance pupil is in the same place the perspective will be the same, even if the rendering is different. The same parts of the same scene will be visible, the same parts of the same things will be blocked by objects closer to the camera, etc.

I found the flaw of my argument. I have ignored the fact that images formed by thin lens may not be what is seen on typical image sensor. If there are two objects of different distances, then one of them is defocused. Computing it's magnification is meaningless. Instead I should check the position of its blurred image on the sensor (the center of the bokeh), which has to do with extending the chief ray to the image plane. The result could be different. I may answer my question if I find it out.

The question has confused between the image formed by the lens and the projection formed on the film.

In this diagram, segment PQ is the object, and P'Q' is the image focused, which conforms to the magnification formula in the question. However, for the picture created on the film, it is the segment R1R2, a blurred defocused area. Here PT is the cheif ray (defined as the ray that passes the center of the lens element) so T is the center of the bokeh ball, and this is the location of the projected object. The two marginal rays define the edge of the bokeh ball.
We see
$$\triangle PQO\sim \triangle TUO\implies \frac{h}{s}=-\frac{\overline{TU}}{D}\implies\overline{TU}=-\frac{hD}{s}$$
Indeed it's the same formula for the projection for a pinhole camera. The focal length does not appear here.
For casual photographers I think this argument is enough.
===
To make it more interesting, @MichaelC has mentioned one can place a pupil here. So let us position a physical aperture stop behind the lens. The entrane pupil is defined as the image of the aperture formed by the lens. We can have these cases:
aperture is placed within f; EP is a virtual image behind it (most common):

aperture is placed outside f; EP is on other side, and object is between the lens and EP

aperture is placed outside f; EP is on other side, and object is in front of EP

To convert between the EP and the aperture (exit pupil)
$$\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{\delta}=\frac{1}{f}$$
By using the appropriate sign convention of d, the three cases can be treated in the same way.
First I would like to get the properties of the cheif ray at the center of the EP. Using geometry:
$$\theta'\approx\tan\theta'=-\frac{h}{s-d}$$
(Note if I do this with the marginal ray - I get the location of the edge of the blur which is used to calculate the circle of confusion / depth of field; That's not the purpose of this question, so I'll pass)
Then pretending the light ray originates from that location, I can trace the ray until it hits the film. ABCD matrix is convenient so I'll use it to simplify things. It can be viewed as the cheif ray going through the air, then the lens, then the air again to hit the film. So:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&D\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-\frac{1}{f}&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&d\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{h}{d-s}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{hDf-hdD+hdf}{fd-fs}\\\frac{hd-hf}{fs-fd}\end{bmatrix}$$
hence the location of the projection is
$$\overline{TU}=\frac{hDf-hdD+hdf}{fd-fs}$$
which has a little of everything including the location of the film and the EP, and the focal length.
If I decrease the distance between PE and the lens, i.e. setting d -> 0 we obtain:
$$\overline{TU}|_{d=0}=-\frac{hD}{s}$$
So the dependency on f has disappeared.
To verify the result, setting d -> infinity (i.e. placing the aperture at the rear focal point), we get an object-space telecentric lens that removes perspective distortion (no dependency on s):
$$\overline{TU}|_{d\rightarrow\infty}=\frac{h(f-D)}{f}$$
Setting d -> 0 (i.e. placing the aperture at the front focal point), we get an image-space telecentric lens (no dependency on D):
$$\overline{TU}|_{d=f}=\frac{hf}{f-s}$$

A lens can only show the same view that you see when standing in that spot. A longer focal length will enlarge what the camera sees, but with the distances along the path all with their same proportional change, determined (or let's say affected) by their distance from where you are standing.
So Focal Length cannot change perspective. Your choice of where to stand (both angle and distance) is the only factor of what you will see there.


For a thin lens focal length does indeed influence perspective as you described.
No thin lens objectives for cameras exist anyway so if you want to be pedantic then focal length is not enough because photographic objectives have entrance pupil at different optical position.

That said, the effect is very negligible except scientific applications, so it's correct to say there's no effect, especially considering (2). If photographer moves the camera to have same framing there cannot be any difference.


My understanding of perspective is the extent to which farther objects appear smaller.

That is not my understanding...
Perspective is the variable that affects the spatial relationships of objects within the scene. I.e. it is not that it makes distant object larger/smaller, but rather that it makes them appear closer to or farther from objects in the foreground. And it is inversely proportional to the distance from the camera to the foreground objects.
I.e. if the camera to subject distance is less than subject to background distance the spatial relationship of those two points is "looser/expanded" (bg objects appear smaller and more distant). And if the camera to subject distance is greater than the subject to background distance their spatial relationship is "tighter/compressed."
If you change the magnification (FL) that relationship is not changed... i.e. the perspective is not changed. The change in magnification (FL) affects both the near and the far objects equally.

Each image you make with your camera, regardless of its format size or focal length used, will display an accurate geometrical representation of the subject as seen by a person viewing this scene, provided the camera lens swaps places with the eye of the human observer.
There are provisos: The image made is viewed from a distance that is the same as the focal length of the taking lens. Given today’s miniature cameras with short lenses, say 50mm or so, such a viewing distance is inconvenient or impossible without optical aid. Enlargement of this image is required to view this image.  Suppose 8X magnification is employed either to make a print or view on a computer screen or by projection.  The viewing distance to maintain the “human perspective” is focal length multiplied by magnification. I this example, 50 X 8 = 400mm = 18 inches.
In summary: An image will display correct perspective provided the image viewing distance is the focal length of the taking lens multiplied by the magnification applied to make the displayed image.
